# Opinions on a statistical error in p values (re: standard deviations, t-test/Kruskal-Wallis) in a published study?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, standard-deviation, kruskal-wallis-test

A large amount of computing resources is required to compute exact probabilities for the Kruskal–Wallis test. Existing software only provides exact probabilities for sample sizes less than about 30 participants. These software programs rely on asymptotic approximation for larger sample sizes.

Exact probability values for larger sample sizes are available. Spurrier (2003) published exact probability tables for samples as large as 45 participants.[7] Meyer and Seaman (2006) produced exact probability distributions for samples as large as 105 participants.[8]

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perusing the paper.** After beating my way through a jungle of ads (and an offer to subscribe to an ad blocker)
I found summary data in your link for the Neutrophil/lymphocyte ratio, expressed as
$2.136 \pm 1.31$ for 107 subjects in the tinnitus group and $2.061 \pm 1.43$ in an independent control group. From the body of the paper, it seems that the numbers
following $\pm$ are sample standard deviations, not 95% margins of error. ["For the descriptive data, the normally distributed values are expressed as mean ± standard deviation."]

The P-value 0.002 for this comparison is given in Table 1. From the description, it seems that this P-value is for a *one-sided* 2-sample t test, but it is not
clear whether it was a pooled or Welch 2-sample t test.

**Failure to confirm significance.** In Minitab software, it is possible to run t tests from summary statistics, in the absence of raw data.

*Welch t test:* Minitab output for the Welch test of $H:\mu_t = \mu_c$ against $H:\mu_t \ne \mu_c$ (not assuming equal population variances) is shown below. The P-value is 0.345, nowhere near significant. 
    Two-Sample T-Test and CI

```
Sample    N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       107  2.14   1.31     0.13
2       107  2.06   1.43     0.14

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.075
95% lower bound for difference:  -0.235
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs >): 
   T-Value = 0.40  P-Value = 0.345  DF = 210
```

*Pooled t test:* With a balanced design (107 subjects in each group), the T-statistic for a pooled test
would be the same as for the Welch test, and with DF = 212, also not significant.

*One-sided tests:* Testing $H:\mu_t \le \mu_c$ against $H:\mu_t > \mu_c$ would give P-values half as large as above for Welch and pooled tests. Neither significant.

**Doubts about normality assumption.** The only substantial clue to the actual data is in the boxplots of Fig. 1. To my eye from these plots, significance of a 2-sample t test seems unlikely. Also, notwithstanding claims of having used Shapiro-Wilk tests to confirm that data are normal, the boxplots show heavy right skewness and many high boxplot 'outliers'. (Perhaps "Neutrophil' and 'lymphocytes', taken *separately* are normal, but certainly *not their ratio.* Ratios are often nonnormal.)

Furthermore, the degree of skewness may be too much for the legendary robustness of the t test against nonnormality to accommodate---even for samples as large as 107.

**From here?** So I am puzzled about the evidence for the most basic claim of the paper.
It may be that some of the other (dozen or so) measurements mentioned in Table 1 *do* show significant differences between tinnitus and control groups, as you suspect.

You might try to replicate P-values for t tests for some of them. (Knowing sample sizes, sample means, and sample standard deviations is enough to use standard formulas
for T statistics and methods for deciding whether to reject, if you don't have suitable software at hand.)

Comment: Depends on version of MTB. Use menus: `STAT > Basic > 2-sample t > Summary data >` fill in blanks.

Comment: Thanks for comment: Not _much_ different. I suspect differences due to rounding errors. Minitab often rounds too much for my taste in its ourput. They claim to keep 14 places or so behind the scenes.